# Building, Debugging, Publish Windows 10 appxbundle using Cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-cordova

I have some Cordova project for Windows 10 i can't Publish anymore because visual studio sopped support for Cordova projects.

Does anyone know how to continue Windows 10 apps developing without visual studio? I Don't need Android or iOS, Just Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio supports and will support Windows 10 apps development without restriction. The **Windows Store** might be blocking new APPX uploads and updates, but this doesn't mean you can't develop Windows 10 apps anymore. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I'm talking about Cordova projects. Visual studio was able to create Cordova based projects, run, debug and Publish them. Now it seems i have to use visual studio code but i can't find support for Windows, only Android and iOS.